# QTableWidgetItem subclass operator<() never getting called when sorting QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, sorting

I wanted to implement a custom sort for my `QTableWidget` so I subclassed `QTableWidgetItem` and re-implemented the `operator<()` function.

```
class FloatFieldTableItem : public QTableWidgetItem
{
public:
    FloatFieldTableItem(qreal theFloat) :
    QTableWidgetItem(),
    _float(theFloat)
    {}

    virtual bool operator<(FloatFieldTableItem const &other) const
    {
        return _float < other.float;
    }

private:
    qreal _float;
};
```

But for some reason the `operator<()` function is never even getting called!

```
tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new FloatFieldTableItem(0.1));
tableWidget->setItem(1, 0, new FloatFieldTableItem(0.3));
tableWidget->setItem(2, 0, new FloatFieldTableItem(6.1));
// This should result in a call to the operator<() function above
tableWidget->sortItems(0);
```

Comment: Though it may seem meaningless, can you also post how you're invoking the operator? Is it in a vector of `FloatFieldTableItem` and invoked implicitly via `std::sort()` Just a little more context if you could please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of your `operator<()` does not match that of `QTableWidgetItem`, so even though it has been declared virtual, it doesn't go into the `vtable` in a manner that allows your `QTableWidget` to even call it.

The signature `QTableWidgetItem`'s `operator<()` takes a `QTableWidgetItem` as a parameter, so you'll have to cast it to your `FloatFieldTableItem` to do what you want.

```
virtual bool operator<(QTableWidgetItem const &other) const
{
    FloatFieldTableItem const *item
        = dynamic_cast<FloatFieldTableItem const*>(&other);
    if(item)
    {
        return _float < item->_float;
    }
    else
    {
        return QTableWidgetItem::operator<(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a C++11 compiler, the keyword `override` was added to the language solely to catch this programming error.

Comment: Ugh, I wish I was using C++11 - this could have saved me some time today.

Comment: @Casey Technically, `override` is not a keyword: it's a context-sensitive identifier (§2.11p2).